# jQuery Circular Content Carousel Autoscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, autoscroll

I found a cool carousel script named [Circular Content Carousel by Tympanus](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/16/circular-content-carousel/). It's almost exactly what I need. When clicking on the "more" link, the respective item moves to the left and a content area will slide out.

What I need to achieve now is to make it **autoscroll** and stopped while **mouseover** on the carousel and when the content area opened.

I'm a newbie in javascript & jquery, so I desperately need an expert help. Can somebody help me customize this carousel?

Here's a link of the working Circular Content Carousel. http://jsfiddle.net/niczcool/x7jxa/2/

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here is an update:

Not the best way, but is going to work

http://jsfiddle.net/x7jxa/3/

Update:

http://jsfiddle.net/x7jxa/4/

Yes, i agree with function, but Fiddle for some reason return an weird error.

Comment: A `Function` is better than a `String` in `setInterval`.

Comment: How do i stop the circular effect

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#ca-container').contentcarousel();
  var int = setInterval("$('.ca-nav-next').trigger('click');",1000);                          
  $('.ca-item').hover(function(){
    clearInterval(int);
  },function(){
    int = setInterval("$('.ca-nav-next').trigger('click');",1000);    
  });
  $('.ca-nav').hover(function(){
    clearInterval(int);
  },function(){
    int = setInterval("$('.ca-nav-next').trigger('click');",1000);    
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. I have just finished modifying the script a bit to allow for it. It is relatively stable and you can change the variables in the script. Its not pretty, but it works, modifications to clean it up welcome. jquery.contentcarousel.js

```
(function($) {
var aux     = {
        // navigates left / right
        navigate    : function( dir, $el, $wrapper, opts, cache ) {

            var scroll      = opts.scroll,
                factor      = 1,
                idxClicked  = 0;

            if( cache.expanded ) {
                scroll      = 1; // scroll is always 1 in full mode
                factor      = 3; // the width of the expanded item will be 3 times bigger than 1 collapsed item 
                idxClicked  = cache.idxClicked; // the index of the clicked item
            }

            // clone the elements on the right / left and append / prepend them according to dir and scroll
            if( dir === 1 ) {
                $wrapper.find('div.ca-item:lt(' + scroll + ')').each(function(i) {
                    $(this).clone(true).css( 'left', ( cache.totalItems - idxClicked + i ) * cache.itemW * factor + 'px' ).appendTo( $wrapper );
                });
            }
            else {
                var $first  = $wrapper.children().eq(0);

                $wrapper.find('div.ca-item:gt(' + ( cache.totalItems  - 1 - scroll ) + ')').each(function(i) {
                    // insert before $first so they stay in the right order
                    $(this).clone(true).css( 'left', - ( scroll - i + idxClicked ) * cache.itemW * factor + 'px' ).insertBefore( $first );
                });
            }

            // animate the left of each item
            // the calculations are dependent on dir and on the cache.expanded value
            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {
                var $item   = $(this);
                $item.stop().animate({
                    left    :  ( dir === 1 ) ? '-=' + ( cache.itemW * factor * scroll ) + 'px' : '+=' + ( cache.itemW * factor * scroll ) + 'px'
                }, opts.sliderSpeed, opts.sliderEasing, function() {
                    if( ( dir === 1 && $item.position().left < - idxClicked * cache.itemW * factor ) || ( dir === -1 && $item.position().left > ( ( cache.totalItems - 1 - idxClicked ) * cache.itemW * factor ) ) ) {
                        // remove the item that was cloned
                        $item.remove();
                    }                       
                    cache.isAnimating   = false;
                });
            });

        },
        // opens an item (animation) -> opens all the others
        openItem    : function( $wrapper, $item, opts, cache ) {
            cache.idxClicked    = $item.index();
            // the item's position (1, 2, or 3) on the viewport (the visible items) 
            cache.winpos        = aux.getWinPos( $item.position().left, cache );
            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').not( $item ).hide();
            $item.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').css( 'left', cache.itemW + 'px' ).stop().animate({
                width   : cache.itemW * 2 + 'px',
                left    : cache.itemW + 'px'
            }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing)
            .end()
            .stop()
            .animate({
                left    : '0px'
            }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing, function() {
                cache.isAnimating   = false;
                cache.expanded      = true;

                aux.openItems( $wrapper, $item, opts, cache );
            });

        },
        // opens all the items
        openItems   : function( $wrapper, $openedItem, opts, cache ) {
            var openedIdx   = $openedItem.index();

            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {
                var $item   = $(this),
                    idx     = $item.index();

                if( idx !== openedIdx ) {
                    $item.css( 'left', - ( openedIdx - idx ) * ( cache.itemW * 3 ) + 'px' ).show().find('div.ca-content-wrapper').css({
                        left    : cache.itemW + 'px',
                        width   : cache.itemW * 2 + 'px'
                    });

                    // hide more link
                    aux.toggleMore( $item, false );
                }
            });
        },
        // show / hide the item's more button
        toggleMore  : function( $item, show ) {
            ( show ) ? $item.find('a.ca-more').show() : $item.find('a.ca-more').hide(); 
        },
        // close all the items
        // the current one is animated
        closeItems  : function( $wrapper, $openedItem, opts, cache ) {
            var openedIdx   = $openedItem.index();

            $openedItem.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').stop().animate({
                width   : '0px'
            }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing)
            .end()
            .stop()
            .animate({
                left    : cache.itemW * ( cache.winpos - 1 ) + 'px'
            }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing, function() {
                cache.isAnimating   = false;
                cache.expanded      = false;
            });

            // show more link
            aux.toggleMore( $openedItem, true );

            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {
                var $item   = $(this),
                    idx     = $item.index();

                if( idx !== openedIdx ) {
                    $item.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').css({
                        width   : '0px'
                    })
                    .end()
                    .css( 'left', ( ( cache.winpos - 1 ) - ( openedIdx - idx ) ) * cache.itemW + 'px' )
                    .show();

                    // show more link
                    aux.toggleMore( $item, true );
                }
            });
        },
        // gets the item's position (1, 2, or 3) on the viewport (the visible items)
        // val is the left of the item
        getWinPos   : function( val, cache ) {
            switch( val ) {
                case 0                  : return 1; break;
                case cache.itemW        : return 2; break;
                case cache.itemW * 2    : return 3; break;
            }
        }
    },
    methods = {
        init        : function( options ) {

            if( this.length ) {

                var settings = {
                    sliderSpeed     : 500,          // speed for the sliding animation
                    sliderEasing    : 'easeOutExpo',// easing for the sliding animation
                    itemSpeed       : 500,          // speed for the item animation (open / close)
                    itemEasing      : 'easeOutExpo',// easing for the item animation (open / close)
                    scroll          : 1             // number of items to scroll at a time
                };

                return this.each(function() {

                    // if options exist, lets merge them with our default settings
                    if ( options ) {
                        $.extend( settings, options );
                    }

                    var $el             = $(this),
                        $wrapper        = $el.find('div.ca-wrapper'),
                        $maincontainer  = $el.find('div.container'),//used for the hover function
                        $isopen         = 0,                        //used to detect if the boxes are opened to stop scrolling
                        $autoscroll     = 1,                        //set to 0 if you dont want autoscroll
                        $asspeed        = 6000,                     //usual js times, currently set to 6 seconds
                        $items          = $wrapper.children('div.ca-item'),
                        cache           = {};

                    // save the with of one item    
                    cache.itemW         = $items.width();
                    // save the number of total items
                    cache.totalItems    = $items.length;

                    // add navigation buttons
                    if( cache.totalItems > 3 )  
                        $el.prepend('<div class="ca-nav"><span class="ca-nav-prev">Previous</span><span class="ca-nav-next">Next</span></div>') 

                    // control the scroll value
                    if( settings.scroll < 1 )
                        settings.scroll = 1;
                    else if( settings.scroll > 3 )
                        settings.scroll = 3;    

                    var $navPrev        = $el.find('span.ca-nav-prev'),
                        $navNext        = $el.find('span.ca-nav-next');

                    // hide the items except the first 3
                    $wrapper.css( 'overflow', 'hidden' );

                    // the items will have position absolute 
                    // calculate the left of each item
                    $items.each(function(i) {
                        $(this).css({
                            position    : 'absolute',
                            left        : i * cache.itemW + 'px'
                        });
                    });

                    // click to open the item(s)
                    $el.find('a.ca-more').live('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                        if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                        cache.isAnimating   = true;
                        $isopen = 1;
                        $(this).hide();
                        var $item   = $(this).closest('div.ca-item');
                        aux.openItem( $wrapper, $item, settings, cache );
                        clearTimeout(tid);
                        return false;
                    });

                    // click to close the item(s)
                    $el.find('a.ca-close').live('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                        if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                        cache.isAnimating   = true;
                        var $item   = $(this).closest('div.ca-item');
                        aux.closeItems( $wrapper, $item, settings, cache );
                        $isopen = 0;
                        return false;
                    });

                    // autoscroll
                    if ($autoscroll == 1){
                        var tid = setTimeout(ascroll, $asspeed);

                        $wrapper.bind('mouseover.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                            clearTimeout(tid);
                        });

                        $wrapper.bind('mouseout.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                            if ($isopen == 0){
                            tid = setTimeout(ascroll, $asspeed);
                            };
                        });

                    };

                    function ascroll() {
                        if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                        cache.isAnimating   = true;
                        aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                        tid = setTimeout(ascroll, $asspeed); // repeat myself
                    };

                    // navigate left
                    $navPrev.bind('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                        if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                        cache.isAnimating   = true;
                        aux.navigate( -1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                    });

                    // navigate right
                    $navNext.bind('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                        if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                        cache.isAnimating   = true;
                        aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                    });

                    // adds events to the mouse
                    $el.bind('mousewheel.contentcarousel', function(e, delta) {
                        if(delta > 0) {
                            if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                            cache.isAnimating   = true;
                            aux.navigate( -1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                        }   
                        else {
                            if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                            cache.isAnimating   = true;
                            aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                        }   
                        return false;
                    });

                });
            }
        }
    };

$.fn.contentcarousel = function(method) {
    if ( methods[method] ) {
        return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
        return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
        $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.contentcarousel' );
    }
};
```

})(jQuery);